# Background Check

Tags: background-check

I just got an offer for a salary position, and they are now going to do a background check. Previously I only had freelance positions that were short-term project basis. In my resume, I listed them with the prefix "freelance-" and only gave years for the dates, without months. Will they consider it a lie that I wasn't clear about exact dates, because they didn't last each full year? Also could they find out any mismatches about my previous hourly wages? I gave the company contacts for references, and I do have good relationships with people from the previous companies. Is there anything I could do-- maybe talk to the hiring manager from this company to clarify about the dates? By the way, my credit record does not have any employment history, maybe because I've always been self-employed.

Answer (score 4):

They're more concerned with criminal offenses and (in some cases) bad credit.  If you weren't *an employee* for all the prior projects, your former clients have no obligation to even answer the telephone.

Don't worry.